# How to create Golang Linux binaries using a Windows host

Tags: docker, linux, windows

When `go build` is issued on a Windows host a .exe binary is created. How to ensure that a Linux binary is created on a Windows host?

The following was tried, but did not solve the issue:

```
GOOS=linux;go build hello-world.go
```

Comment: replace the semicolon with space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily set the target operating system and processor architecture using the environment variables **GOOS** and **GOARCH** respectively. So, as you want to build it for linux operating system, following command with above environment variables will do,

```
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o hello main.go
```

Here is the [list of all the supported operating system](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment) with which you can easily do cross compilation using Go lang.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `docker build` opens a new shell and `export` is needed. The following command created a Linux binary:

```
export GOOS=linux; go build hello-world.go
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows also has a one-liner solution, just a bit uglier than the linux version. Any of the below lines will do the job:

```
cmd /C "SET GOOS=linux&& SET GOARCH=amd64&& go build main.go"
cmd /C "SET "GOOS=linux" && SET "GOARCH=amd64" && go build main.go"
```

Be careful, if you just write `...SET GOOS=linux && SET ...` then you will get an error message

```
cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64
```

because there will be an extra space after the value `linux`. In order to avoid this, use either the condensed form `linux&&` or the other version with quotation marks.